# json onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The below code is executing/sending data on body load but i want to make it onclick like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>

<script> 

$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
            var table_body = "";
            $.each(data, function(k, ip) {
                save_info =   ip +","+location.hostname+",var1,var2";
        /* save_info= ip +","+location.hostname+",var1,var2"; */
            });

 $(document).ready(function() {
    var json_object = {"data": save_info};

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.example.com/test/data.php",
        data: json_object,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(json_object) {
            console.log(json_object);
            $("#saved").text("Data has been saved.");
        },
        error: function(json_object) {
            console.log(json_object);
            $("#saved").text("Failed to save data !");
        }
    });
})
        });


</script>
</head>
<body>  
<a href="#" onclick='getJSON()'> click here</a>
<!-- I want to make json send data when this click event happens, suggest how to write onclick here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Please also suggest me if there is any alternative way using jquery/javascript to record this user's IP address & hostname, I want to send them to a remote page as parameters where it'll be saved.

Comment: Where is your getJSON() function?

Comment: "Please also suggest me if there is any alternative way using jquery/javascript to record this user's IP address & hostname, I want to send them to a remote page as parameters where it'll be saved. " - this is a totally separate question, so should be posted separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getJSON() is not a function in itself. You never declared the function.

Do this:

```
function getJSON() {

  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
    var table_body = "";
    $.each(data, function(k, ip) {
      save_info =   ip +","+location.hostname+",var1,var2";
    });
  });

}
```